# How to return site_url() without https://

Tags: php, site-url

I am retrieving the site URL and creating a shortcode to display it. However when i return the site URL as expected it contains the full string including https://

How can i return the site url without the `https://` part?  So instead of https://siteurl.com it would just say siteurl.com

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_shortcode( 'site_url', function( $atts = null, $content = null ) {
        return site_url();
    } );

} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below method

```
$site_url = site_url();
$url = preg_replace("(^https?://)", "", $site_url );
return $url;
```

Comment: Thanks mate! That makes perfect sense